# Implementation size of post quantum schemes

Tags: rsa, elliptic-curves, post-quantum-cryptography, performance

I was comparing classical schemes with post-quantum schemes. Therefore I was interested in the [round three](https://www.pqsecurity.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/Round-3.pdf) candidates of the NIST standardization process. So far I know, that those post-quantum schemes need a much bigger key-, signature- and ciphertext sizes. Regarding performance, I concluded that the difference is not significant.

Now I was wondering, how the size of the implementations differs. I thought it might be interesting for applications with limited storage space. But I couldn't find any good sources that present the necessary data. So my question is: How much do the methods differ, especially classical ones like RSA, ECC and the post-quantum schemes? Does such a comparison make sense at all?

Comment: There is an evaluation criterion called 4.C.1 (c) which is part of the *flexibility* of the algorithm which reads: "The algorithms can be implemented securely and efficiently on a wide variety of platforms, including constrained environments, such as smart
cards.". But I'm not sure if this requirement is directly referenced by the submissions. I presume it is. So " Does such a comparison make sense at all?" yes, absolutely, and it has or should have been taken into account. Of course, for general purpose CPU's a KiB or more of machine code is not so significant.

Comment: I found a paper with a comparison, but it didn't state any educational institution (TBH, it looked good though, but I'll have to research a bit more before posting a link).

Comment: Did you found a link so far @MaartenBodewes ?